# dockerの本番使用の是非について

Tags: macos, docker

dockerを使用してwebアプリのテスト環境を構築したのですが、上司から許可が降りませんでした。
理由は、レスポンスが"悪そう"とのことでした。

確かに私のテスト環境ではwebからのレスポンスが悪かったです。
M1 MACとUTMという仮想ソフトで、RHEL8のx86-64版をエミュレートしていたので遅かったのですが、それがwebアプリのレスポンスの悪さの主な原因かどうかはわかりません。

そこで質問ですが、

1.dockerの本番使用は現実的か、どれくらい現場で使われているのか
(会社は田舎の中小企業です。docker使えて当たり前の時代になりつつあるのに、使用できないと言われて少し面食らいました)

2.dockerのレスポンスの改善方法
(dockerが悪いのか私の構築が悪いのか。わかりませんが"悪そう"で諦めるのはもったいない気がしています、田舎の会社ですがdockerデビューしてみたいです)

アバウトな質問ですみません、どちらかでも良いので回答頂けたらと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「悪そう」というフィードバックに対して「ほかでも使っています」「このぐらいレスポンス改善できます」と上司に言うことはできますが。それで上司の許可が下りるかは別の話のような気もします。大事なことは、上司と会話して「どのような数字をだしてどのような回答をすれば許可してもらえるか」をしっかり握ることが大事かなと思います。

Comment: 単に「悪そう」や「遅い」だと個人の感覚に過ぎないので、具体的な数値を挙げた方が議論がしやすいです。あくまで "テスト環境" として使うのであれば多少レスポンスが悪くてもよさそうな気はしますが… / Mac で使う上での「遅い」は、例えばこんな記事がありました。[Docker + Mac どうする問題](https://tech.mirrativ.stream/entry/2021/12/21/125127)

Comment: 何を理由にx86_64エミュレーションをしているかによるのですが、私の知る限りM1 Macでのx86_64エミュレーションはとても遅いです。[M1 Pro + Docker for Macが遅い - Qiita](https://qiita.com/naomichi-y/items/1e676139e3f9fbc75d3c)でも実測値が取られていますが、肌感としては同じで倍以上の差があるようです。なので、docker上でもARMのまま実行するだとか、あるいはMac上でDockerを動かさない、というのも手でしょうが。もちろん既出記事のようにDocker on Macにはバインドマウントが遅いといった事情もあります。

Comment: あっ、本題は「本番で」でしたね。Macで遅いのには**(HWの)仮想化**というネックが存在しているためです。macOS上でLinuxを実行しているのです。一方で通常の本番環境ではLinuxサーバー等でdockerを実行しますが、こちらでは通常そういったフェーズははさみません(最近でてきたDocker Desktop for Linux みたいなのは別)。そもそもDockerの文脈での本来の姿である仮想化とは実質強いchroot。エミュレーションはせずダイレクトにHWを扱うわけなのでそれにより遅くなるかといえば、基本的にそんなことはなく無視できるレベルでCPUやRAMを食う可能性がある程度では？(肌感ですが)

Comment: Dockerを運用で使うというのは事例としてあります（Docker 本番 運用 事例で検索してみてください。）https://teratail.com/questions/266808 あたりも参考になるかと。

Answer (score 3):

> 1. dockerの本番使用は現実的か、どれくらい現場で使われているのか

単に Docker やコンテナ技術を使うだけという意味であれば、Amazon ECS や Kubenetes を利用している場合は使っているので、利用例は世の中にたくさん存在します。オンプレミスの場合でも事例はあり、検索すると色々と出てきます。

コンテナ技術を使ってみたいというだけではなくて何故コンテナ技術を使うのかの理由まで言語化すると、類似事例を探しやすそうです。

> 2. dockerのレスポンスの改善方法

質問者さんの環境では、M1 Mac をサーバーにしてそこに向けてアクセスするのでしょうか？　そうでなくて実際には RHEL サーバーにデプロイするのであれば、エミュレーションが無くなるので前提条件が変わります。使用方法にもよりますがおそらくエミュレーションがボトルネックになっているのでまずはそこを解消して計測してみてください。